# ng-bootstrap popover on content from database

Tags: angular, database, ng-bootstrap

I'd like to add nb-bootstrap popovers to select text portions which are coming from a database.

I've implemented ng-popovers elsewhere successfully, inside the code base in the .ts files. Doing so inside the content from the database, the first problem was that Angular would strip out the bindings required for ng-popover.

By creating a safehtml pipe, the problem with the stripping out of code went away. However, the bindings are non-functional and my ng-template element with the content I'd like to popup is rendered inline.

In doing the research to solve this, I gathered that this might be that the bindings get checked / registered before my content is displayed - that in essence this is intended behaviour.

**Is there a standard way of implementing ng-popovers on contented pulled from the database?** The project is large, and I need to avoid hackish solutions. I'm open to using some method other than ng-popovers that are better suited to implementation on content inside a database.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your data, but imagine we has a text like

```
text="[=Lorem=] ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do [=eiusmod=] 
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in [=voluptate=] velit
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est [=laborum.=]"
```

And a serie of popover defined in an array like

```
popover=[{text:"tooltip1",title:"title 1"},
         {text:"tooltip2",title:"title 2"},
         {text:"tooltip3",title:"title 3"},
         {text:"tooltip4",title:"title 4"}]
```

The idea is generate an array of object with the properties text,word and popover

```
const part=this.text.split("[=");
    let count:number=0
    part.forEach((x,index)=>{
      let f=x.indexOf("=]")
      if (f>=0)
      {
        this.data.push({
          text:part[index-1],
          word:part[index].substr(0,f),
          popover:this.popover[count]
          })
        part[index]=part[index].substr(f+2)
        count++
      }
    })
        this.data.push({
          text:part[part.length-1]
        })
  }
```

Then, we can use this data in our .html

```
  <div class="container">
    <div style="display:inline" *ngFor="let d of data">{{d.text}}
      <button *ngIf="d.popover" type="button" class="btn btn-link"
         [ngbPopover]="d.popover.text"
         [popoverTitle]="d.popover.title">
      {{d.word}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can see the result in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wv2hup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** there's a problem if our text has html tags becaouse the "divs" break the html tags, sorry

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Eliseo. I was not able to use the code, since we have volumes of content in the database, and our aim was to keep the popover data with the rest of the surrounding content. Since the text are just short snippets, we were able to implement a CSS-only, tool-tip solution as described at  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp